# Angular UI-Router nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am trying to get nested views to work in which after logging in it sends you to `in.html` from there all links link to a `ui-view` within `in.html`. Currently all links go to a "new" page

index.html

```
<!-- more HTML -->
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">
<!--<div id="loading"><span>Loading</span></div>-->

<div ui-view="default"></div>
</body>
<!-- more HTML -->
```

in.html

```
<a ui-sref="online">Online Users</a>
<div ui-view="main"></div>
```

app.js routes

```
var $td = $config.TPL_DIR;

$stateProvider
    .state('auth', {
        url: '/auth',
        views: {
            "default": {
                controller: 'AuthController as auth',
                templateUrl: $td + 'login.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('loggedin', {
        url: '/in',
        views: {
            "default": {
                templateUrl: $td + 'in.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('online', {
        url: '/online',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'OnlineController as online',
                templateUrl: $td + 'online.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making some subviews and then changing the ui-view from in there. Something like

```
.state('loggedin.another_view', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        "main": {
            templateUrl: $td + 'partial.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Since `loggedin` is the parent view, when the router looks for `main`, it will look within the `loggedin` context for the view. It will load `partial.html` into your view.

Answer (score 0):

Changed state to loggedin.online

```
.state('loggedin.online', {
        url: '/online',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'OnlineController as online',
                templateUrl: $td + 'online.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Change link to

```
<a ui-sref=".online">Online Users</a>
<div ui-view="main"></div>
```